Proof of Strong Consistency of mean of Beta posterior distribution
Suppose that we have random variable $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n} \sim^{iid} \text{Bernoulli}(p_{0})$ with $p_{0}$ true unknown probability in $[0,1]$. Now, I want to implement Bayesian machinery to infer the true unknown probability $p_{0}$. To do that the first step is to define a prior distribution on my random variable $p$ which is a guess of $p_{0}$ and I place a $\text{Beta}(a,b)$ distribution with $a,b>0$. Then I can derive the posterior distribution conditional on the realizations $X_{1}=x_{1}, X_{2}=x_{2}, ..., X_{n}=x_{n}$
$$p|X_{1}=x_{1}, X_{2}=x_{2}, ..., X_{n}=x_{n}\sim \text{Beta}(a+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}, b + n - \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i})$$
Up to now everything goes as normal. Let us denote the mean of the posterior distribution as $T_{n} = \frac{a+\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}{a+b+n}$, and I used capital $X_{i}$ since it is a random variable.
The part that I'm not sure, is how to prove the Strong consistency of the $T_{n}$. By saying that I mean
$$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }T_{n} = p_{0})  = 1 \ \ (*)$$

My way of though:
First, I want to check what is going on with the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }T_{n}$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{a+\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}{a+b+n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}{n} \ \ (1)$$
We know that $(X_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ are iid and the $\mathbb{E}[X_{i}= p] < \infty$ with $\mathbb{E}[X_{i}] =p_{0}$. Then we can make use of the Strong Law of Large numbers which states that
$$\mathbb{P}(\lim \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}{n}  = p_{0}) = 1$$
which is exactly the kind of convergence that we need in $(*)$. Then we can rewrite $(*)$ we have
the desired result
$$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }T_{n} = \lim \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}{n} = p_{0}) = 1$$

Is this a valid way of proving Strong consistency and also the $p_{0}$ is a single unknown value, how can we account and show the consistency for all the possible values that $p_{0}$ can take?

It looks fine to me.
